# List Comprehension and traversing through a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

```
[k for k in range (1,42) if k%2 != 0]
```

output: `[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 29, 31, 33, 35, 37, 39, 41]`

Now, I want to make it to:

`[-1, 3, -5, 7, -9, 11, -13, 15, -17, 19, -21, 23, -25, 27, -29, 31, -33, 35, -37, 39, -41]`

So I tried:

```
def test(N):
    k = []
    for i in range (1,N+1):
        if(i%2 != 0):
            k.append(i)
    for b in k[::2]:       <--- it changes the value but doesn't update the list
        b = -b
    return k
test(43)
```

Any ideas or suggestions on how to approach this problem? Or the other question is, how could I traverse the even numbered index in the list while updating the element to a negative value

Comment: Maybe do something with `k%4`

Comment: Looks like an alternating series if you've taken Calculus. Try multiplying by `(-1)**(k + 1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
numbers = (k for k in range(1, 42) if k%2 != 0)
[x * [-1, 1][n % 2] for n, x in enumerate(numbers)]
```

Output:

```
[-1, 3, -5, 7, -9, 11, -13, 15, -17, 19, -21, 23, -25, 27, -29, 31, -33, 35, -37, 39, -41]
```

### Performance

The approach using modulo is a bit faster than the one for alternating series as suggest by Malik Brahimi in a comment:

```
%%timeit
numbers = (k for k in range(1, 420000) if k%2 != 0)
[x * (-1)**(n + 1) for n, x in enumerate(numbers)]
1 loops, best of 3: 263 ms per loop

%%timeit
numbers = (k for k in range(1, 420000) if k%2 != 0)
[x * [-1, 1][n % 2] for n, x in enumerate(numbers)]
1 loops, best of 3: 210 ms per loop
```

Comment: Looks like an alternating series if you've taken Calculus. Try multiplying by `(-1)**(k + 1)`

Comment: @MalikBrahimi Thanks for the hint. Added some performance measurements for the different approaches.

Comment: @MikeMüller That's a very complicated list comprehension! But thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
[k if k%4==3 else -k for k in range (1,42) if k%2 != 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

`b` is a reference to the (immutable) integer stored in k. By updating b to equal -b, you're not modifying the list, you're simply changing the thing that b referecnes, for the int 2 object to the int -2 object. You might be better off just doing the negation as you build the list:

```
def test(N):
    k = []
    for i in range (1,N+1, 2): # i increases in steps of 2
        if i % 4 == 1:
            i = -i
        k.append(i)
    return k

test(43)
```